# Database query in Kohana only shows the SQL and not the result rows

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-db

I just started to using the Kohana framework and I'm trying to execute a few queries, but after spending a couple hours in documentation and running some tests all I have is this:

```
class Controller_Test extends Controller {
    public function action_index()
    {
       $query = DB::select()->from('test')->where('test', '=', '1');
       echo $query  
    }
}
```

Now, if try to run this all it does is echo my SQL.

How do I get the actual data from my database? I know that I could do something like:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($query));
echo $row[0];
```

and it would work; but I guess that's just completely stupid, since I'm using a framework and there has to be built-in method(s) for this.

Comment: by the way, usefull for you will be great official documentation about DB-module in ko3:
http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/database/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've built up the query you'll then need to turn that into a `Database_Query` object using the `execute()` method so you can get values to run through.

If you want to deal with the results of the query as an array, you can add the `as_array()` method after the execute like so:

```
$query = DB::select()->from('test')->where('test', '=', '1')
                     ->execute()->as_array();
```

If you're only dealing with a single row, and you know you only need a single row, you can change that to `current()`:

```
$query = DB::select()->from('test')->where('test', '=', '1')
                     ->execute()->current();
```

Then you can extract as needed when you loop through the array:

```
foreach ($query as $row)
{
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

Comment: Also, if you use Database_Query::as_object() before Database_Query::execute() Database_Result::current() will return a object instead of an array, and Database::as_array() will return an array of objects.

Answer (score 5):

You should be aware that you're actually building the Database_Query object, so there has to be something to execute it in the end, right?

`$results = DB::select('*')->from('table')->execute();`

and then you can normally loop through these:

`foreach ($results as $result) { echo $result->id; }`

Comment: I've tried running your code, but i get this error
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

To get row:

```
$query = DB::select('p.id')
            ->select_array(array('p.title', array('p.title', 'pocket') ))
            ->from(array($this->_table_name, 'p'))
            ->limit(1);

echo $query->execute()->get('id');
```

To show query:

```
echo $query->compile();
```